# How can I test if a chrono::DateTime<Local> falls within certain times of day?

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

I want to compare the current local time to a constant time range, but my current solution seems more difficult than I'd expect.

I can construct a `chrono::DateTime<Local>` with `Local::now()`. I can then laboriously find out if `now` lies in a particular time range like so:

```
let current_hour = now.hour();
let current_minute = now.minute();

// see if `now` lies between 06:00 and 23:00
current_hour >= 6 && current_hour < 23

// note the inelegance of the syntax and the potential for fencepost errors
```

If I want to check the range from 06:12–23:15, the problem becomes much worse because I have to check if the hour is equal to 6 and then if the minutes are greater than 12 and then check — zzzzz...

That's boring. I can try string representations with `parse_from_rfc2822`, but then I have to first emit the current date and then edit in the time of day and then check for parsing errors and now I'm sleeping again.

I imagine I'm just reading the [chrono documentation](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/struct.DateTime.html) wrong. If I were to implement the library, I would try to build a `TimeOfDay<Local>` datatype which implements `Ord`, thereby allowing idiomatic range checking. I figure it's already there somewhere and I'm just missing it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71876855/idiomatic-way-to-check-if-a-chronodatetimeutc-is-within-date-and-time-range

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DateTime` objects have a function called [`time()`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.time), which returns a [`NaiveTime`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveTime.html) object representing the time of day. `NaiveTime` implements `PartialOrd`, and has a factory function [`from_hms(hour, min, sec)`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveTime.html#method.from_hms). Using `from_hms`, you can create an upper bound and lower bound `NaiveTime`, and then compare using standard operators.

```
let low = NaiveTime::from_hms(6, 12, 0);
let high = NaiveTime::from_hms(23, 15, 0);
let time_of_day = Local::now().time();

if (time_of_day > low) && (time_of_day < high) {
    // do stuff...
} else {
    // do something else...
};
```

[Playground link for completeness.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=60860ef62dc030c006b24e521f82fac7&version=stable)

Comment: And when [issue 32311](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32311) is completed, it will be even prettier.

Comment: @Shepmaster - I suppose you mean there'll be a `TimeRange` struct with a `.contains` method for this kind of problem?

Comment: I mean that [you'll be able to replace your method with the existing `Range` struct](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cc7c00d1bbba2d82fd9c3159bdee632f&version=nightly). That's the beauty of generics and composability ;-).