# Idiomatic way to check if a chrono::DateTime<Utc> is within date and time range?

Tags: datetime, rust, rust-chrono

I am curious if there is an idiomatic way to check if a `chrono::DateTime<Utc>` is within a time range. In my use case I just need to check if the `DateTime` falls within the next half hour, from current time.

This is what I put together so far. Its using `timestamp()` attribute to get a raw (unix) timestamp I can work with.

```rust
use chrono::prelude::*;
use chrono::Duration;

#[inline(always)]
pub fn in_next_half_hour(input_dt: DateTime<Utc>) -> bool {
    in_future_range(input_dt, 30 * 60)
}

/// Check if a `DateTime` occurs within the following X seconds from now.
pub fn in_future_range(input_dt: DateTime<Utc>, range_seconds: i64) -> bool {
    let utc_now_ts = Utc::now().timestamp();
    let input_ts = input_dt.timestamp();

    let within_range = input_ts > utc_now_ts && input_ts <= utc_now_ts + range_seconds;

    within_range
}
```

My test cases are something like this:

```
fn main() {
    let utc_now = Utc::now();

    let input_dt = utc_now - Duration::minutes(15);
    assert_eq!(false, in_next_half_hour(input_dt));

    let input_dt = utc_now + Duration::minutes(15);
    assert_eq!(true, in_next_half_hour(input_dt));

    let input_dt = utc_now + Duration::minutes(25);
    assert_eq!(true, in_next_half_hour(input_dt));

    let input_dt = utc_now + Duration::minutes(35);
    assert_eq!(false, in_next_half_hour(input_dt));

    let input_dt = utc_now - Duration::days(2);
    assert_eq!(false, in_next_half_hour(input_dt));

    let input_dt = utc_now + Duration::days(3);
    assert_eq!(false, in_next_half_hour(input_dt));
}
```

I am curious if there is a more idiomatic approach to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you convert everything to `chrono::DateTime` and `chrono::Duration`, things get a lot simpler:

```rust
use chrono::prelude::*;
use chrono::Duration;

#[inline(always)]
pub fn in_next_half_hour(input_dt: DateTime<Utc>) -> bool {
    in_future_range(input_dt, Duration::minutes(30))
}

/// Check if a `DateTime` occurs within the following X seconds from now.
pub fn in_future_range(input_dt: DateTime<Utc>, range_dur: Duration) -> bool {
    let utc_now_dt = Utc::now();
    let within_range = utc_now_dt < input_dt && input_dt <= utc_now_dt + range_dur;
    within_range
}

fn main() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Yep, that's the approach I was actually thinking of switching to. Interestingly enough, I timed it and the approach with `.timestamp()` actually comes out about 2x faster, assuming I cache the `Utc::now().timestamp()` value rather than calculating it each time (same with `Utc::now()` for the other version). Though I still like the version with `chrono::Duration`, as I agree it's more idiomatic overall.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Is in a debug or release build? I'd be surprised if the two calls to `.timestamp()` don't get optimized away.